# Using htaccess to redirect http to https for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I've correctly enabled HTTPS redirect with the code below.
After visiting one of the HTTPS pages, all other urls are inheriting the previous HTTPS. How can I force all other pages to HTTP?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/checkout|/downloads|/all-products)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://websitename.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(checkout|downloads|all-products)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://websitename.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(checkout|downloads|all-products)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://websitename.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm getting a redirect to websitename.com/index.php. Do I have this organized incorrectly?

Comment: For which URL you got redirected to `websitename.com/index.php`?

Comment: Each one /(checkout|downloads|all-products) redirects to the index for some reason.

Comment: That is not from this code if you have it exactly same way. Can you open firebug and then try loading that URL to see if you're getting 2 redirects by any chance.

Comment: Okay, I'll do some more digging. Thanks so much for your help!